# Compare bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, game-physics

I am trying to develop a `shoot colored balls game`. I know this is an age old game.

My question is: 
    if I shoot a green ball towards a set of balls when it goes over balls how it can find out what colored ball it is (bitmap). All the colored balls would be moving. As a scenario for ex: I shoot a green bullet ball towards a green target ball which is moving. Now in between a red ball comes in the way. My green bullet ball should pass through it towards the green target ball. I used co-ordinate comparison and bitmap comparison (greenbulletballbitmap.sameAs(redinbetweenballbitmap). Since these bitmaps are all pre-defined how can I on the fly get which bitmap it is that has come in between?. Hope you all understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

Make a model for a Ball ie.

---

```
public class Ball
{

    String id; //or color
    Bitmap bitmap;

    String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then just use `if(ballA.getId() != ballB.getId() ) { *your code* } //or getColor() instead`.

Also instead of comparing bitmap, it is much more efficient (and a whole lot faster) if you just compute whether `Rect` for Ball A and the `Rect` for Ball B intersect (look up computing rect intersection).

Answer (score 0):

Separate your "View" (bitmaps) from your "Controller" (balls which move and interact).

If you have a game with green balls and red balls, make colour (or team, or something) a data item in the game itself.  Then when you decide later you want 10 different green ball bitmaps for artistic reasons the code will all still work, your comparison is just (a.colour == b.colour), you can easily write test cases for it without testing a GUI ...